# How to decode base64 encoded image with JS/PHP? (previously encoded with Actionscript)

Tags: javascript, php, image, actionscript-3, base64

I have an image encoded to base64, made with an ActionScript function:

```
private static const BASE64_CHARS:String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

public static function encodeByteArray(_arg1:ByteArray):String {
   var _local3:Array;
   var _local5:uint;
   var _local6:uint;
   var _local7:uint;
   var _local2 = "";
   var _local4:Array = new Array(4);
   _arg1.position = 0;
   while (_arg1.bytesAvailable > 0) {
        _local3 = new Array();
        _local5 = 0;
        while ((((_local5 < 3)) && ((_arg1.bytesAvailable > 0)))) {
            _local3[_local5] = _arg1.readUnsignedByte();
            _local5++;
        };
        _local4[0] = ((_local3[0] & 252) >> 2);
        _local4[1] = (((_local3[0] & 3) << 4) | (_local3[1] >> 4));
        _local4[2] = (((_local3[1] & 15) << 2) | (_local3[2] >> 6));
        _local4[3] = (_local3[2] & 63);
        _local6 = _local3.length;
        while (_local6 < 3) {
            _local4[(_local6 + 1)] = 64;
            _local6++;
        };
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < _local4.length) {
            _local2 = (_local2 + BASE64_CHARS.charAt(_local4[_local7]));
            _local7++;
        };
    };
    return (_local2);
}
```

Now I'm trying to decode (with no success) the string in JS/PHP and have back the image.
Here is the Actionscript decoding function:

```
public static function decodeToByteArray(_arg1:String):ByteArray{
    var _local6:uint;
    var _local7:uint;
    var _local2:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var _local3:Array = new Array(4);
    var _local4:Array = new Array(3);
    var _local5:uint;
    while (_local5 < _arg1.length) {
        _local6 = 0;
        while ((((_local6 < 4)) && (((_local5 + _local6) < _arg1.length)))) {
            _local3[_local6] = BASE64_CHARS.indexOf(_arg1.charAt((_local5 + _local6)));
            _local6++;
        };
        _local4[0] = ((_local3[0] << 2) + ((_local3[1] & 48) >> 4));
        _local4[1] = (((_local3[1] & 15) << 4) + ((_local3[2] & 60) >> 2));
        _local4[2] = (((_local3[2] & 3) << 6) + _local3[3]);
        _local7 = 0;
        while (_local7 < _local4.length) {
            if (_local3[(_local7 + 1)] == 64){
                break;
            };
            _local2.writeByte(_local4[_local7]);
            _local7++;
        };
        _local5 = (_local5 + 4);
    };
    _local2.position = 0;
    return (_local2);
}
```

I tried to convert the decoding Aactionscript function to JS but I'm missing the `new ByteArray();` I don't know how to manage that.
I need a way to decode the encoded image string back to an image.
Here a sample base64 string of an image, encoded with the "encodeByteArray" function:

[sample base64 encoded string](http://bygiro.com/images/encoded.txt)

thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To output your base64 image use this format:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=" />
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work, because the base64 encoding, apparently, is not standard and it doesn't work. that's why I'm asking help here.

Comment: I added a sample string, it works when encoding/decoding using those functions "encodeByteArray" and "decodeToByteArray"